# Magento just stops loading layout from time to time - why?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have a problem with my Magento 1.9.x store. From time to time it stops loading the CSS files for no clear reason. The log files contain no information.

I looked at the source code and normally my CSS is loaded like this: https://www.example.com/skin/frontend/mytheme/default/css/styles.css

After the crash, the paths to the CSS files look like `/frontend/mytheme/default/css/styles.css`. So the `domain` and `skin` is missing.

Cleaning the var/cache folder solves the problem temporarily.

Any idea what I can try to solve or even debug this?

Thanks a lot for helping :)!

Comment: What is set to your store base urls in config?

Comment: https:// www.example.com/... where ... is media, skin, js and so on.

Comment: I dont understand your question.